# app.facebook.com/mygame didn't work

Tags: subdomain, facebook-apps

I have an app on facebook, I'm hosting this app on a subdomain (mygame.mydomain.com).
When I click game on app center or direct link (www.facebook.com/appcenter/mygame) there is no problem, but if I want to redirect on link "app.facebook.com/mygame" it didn't work.

I couldn't understand what's problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

isn't it "apps.facebook.com"?

And also, I think "apps.facebook.com doesn't work anymore. Because whenever I tried opening an app using that url, it redirected me to "facebook.com/appcenter/"